# how can i compare if a loaded dll is the same as on disc

Tags: c#, .net, dll, hash

I have an application that loads a copy of X.dll. How can I check if the original X.dll is different from the X.dll that is loaded.

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
static void Check()
{   
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(X.Y));

    assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Dump();

    byte[] loadedDllHash = GetAssemblyHash(assembly);

    byte[] fileOnDiskHash = GetFileHash(@"C:\foo\X.dll");
}


static byte[] GetAssemblyHash(Assembly assembly)
{
    //this returns null. How can I calculate the hash of the assembly?
    using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("X.dll").Dump())
    {
        return CalculateHash(stream);
    }
}

static byte[] GetFileHash(string filePath)
{
    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        return CalculateHash(stream);
    }
}

static byte[] CalculateHash(Stream stream)
{
    using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
    {
        return sha256.ComputeHash(stream);
    }
}

static bool CompareByteArrays(byte[] a, byte[] b)
{
    if (a.Length != b.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != b[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: It seems that you have a solution. Is there a problem with it? What is your real question?

Comment: But is there a guarantee that the entire assembly is loaded into memory? I don't think so. It probably isn't possible to compute the hash of a loaded assembly. Or if it is, it's unlikely that the computed value would be the same as what you get from computing the hash on a disk file. The in-memory representation of the assembly is not a copy of what's on disk.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to implement some kind of ad-hoc security check. Any reason not to just embrace the .NET way of doing things and create a [strong-named assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/strong-named)?